# Line items with "Inline Entity Form" module

Tags: 7, commerce

https://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form

> Requires integration code to be provided for each entity type that can be referenced.
>   Supports the commerce_product (including Commerce AutoSKU integration) and commerce_line_item, **node**, taxonomy_term entity types out of the box.

I have two custom types, products and purchases. products is the master, purchases are individual line items.

I have tried following the instructions but no widget type *"Inline entity form"* is ever available and certainly no "purchases" editable via the "products" form...

There is some integration code required to make use but the docs also state it works out of the box for **"nodes"** as I have boldified above...are custom types not "nodes"???

Comment: What type of field have you added? It needs to be a multiple entity reference from the _parent_ to the _child_, not the other way around. Then the widget will be available for the field on the parent

Comment: All I see is "node, term, user references" in the parent when editing fields...is "multiple entity reference" a new type added when module enabled? Inline Entity form module is enabled...or do you mean I need to add multiple "node reference" fields to the parent for each line item?

Comment: Nope... _"Supports commerce_product_reference, commerce_line_item_reference and entityreference fields."_ It will only work with the types of fields listed there

Comment: Im case you're not familiar: https://drupal.org/project/entityreference

Comment: OK...might be it :)

Comment: Got it working...kind of...widget type is "inline entity form - multiple values" but I can only seem to add one line item per node...

Comment: Is the _field_ multiple cardinality? If so you should see an 'Add' button

Comment: Number of values to unlimited solved the problem...thanks for all your help :)